# Visio Selected Page Event

Tags: events, visio

I want to do something when the selected (active) page is changed in Visio document. Is there any ways that I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution...

It can be done by handling WindowTurnedToPage event, fired by Window object.